# Refresh navigation from other component

Tags: c#, navigation, refresh, mudblazor

I have a problem, I'm trying to refresh the navigation of another component.
In the navigation, I have Mudbadge as one item, which displays the number of notifications.

```
<MudNavLink><MudBadge>text</MudBadge></MudNavLink>
```

OnClick it redirects me to another page that only has one child component. This component has an activity that displays a dialog. After closing the dialog, I want to refresh the number of notifications. Refresh is the same method as first load data to binded property.
I don't know how to refresh navigation when dialog onClose.

I tried delegates and Actions, and it shows me 'access' to refreshing method from navigation class, but it is always null becouse i try to pass delegate as  custom parameter.

```
<MudNavLink Icon="..." Href="..." NavigationContext="@this"></MudNavLink>
```

NavigationContext is my custom prerty and it seems dont work becouse is always null.
It doesnt work. I have other idea to make this class or variable global, but dont know how.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your code and you could also include images to describe how it's working now and how you'd like it to work.